# Cannot login to Azure Powershell without an interactive prompt

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to run a PowerShell script on a continuous integration build server to automatically deploy using Azure Powershell.

I cannot get around having to deal with a prompt that asks for credentials when trying to run the script.

This is how I'm logging in:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object PSCredential("deployment@mysubscriptionname.onmicrosoft.com", $password)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred
```

And this is one of the commands which interactively prompts to enter a password even after I've already logged in:

```
Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName my-vault-name -Name MySecret
```

How can I avoid the prompt and use Azure Powershell for deploying on a build server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a service principal to authenticate with Azure PowerShell without the need for an interactive prompt. Creation of a service principal is documented [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/).

Comment: I have tried using a service principal, and I've given it access to the ResourceGroup that owns the KeyVault.  However, when logging in with the service principal it cannot access the keyvault.  I get this error: `Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Operation "get" is not allowed`

Comment: Did you add the service principal to the Key Vault Contributors role?

Comment: You need to authorize the service principal in the key vault via powershell: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/#authorize

Comment: @Neil I tried adding the service principal to the "Key Vault Contributor" role and still get the same error.  I also tried the "Owner" role.  Neither are working.

Comment: @BenV Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy worked.  (I didn't realize it had an optional ServicePrincipal parameter).